# Injectivity proof of multiple function composition

Tags: calculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Given two functions $h(x)$ and $f(x)$, with $x \in X \subset \mathbb{R}^6$, with the first $3$ elements of $X$ being a unit vector.
I want to prove that a map $F$ given as

$F = \begin{bmatrix} h(x) \\ h(f(x)) \\ h(f(f(x)))\\ \vdots \end{bmatrix}$,

with up to $N$ compositions is injective.

The function $h$ is defined as
$h(x) = Cx$, with $C = [I_{3\times3} \, 0_{3\times3}]$.

As for $f$, we have $f(x): X \rightarrow X$, and $f(x) \neq x$.

Applying the definition of infectivity I can prove that for up to $N = 2$, $F$ is invective, i.e.,

$F_1 = \begin{bmatrix} h(x) \\ h(f(x)) \end{bmatrix}$, and $F_2 = \begin{bmatrix} h(x) \\ h(f(x)) \\ h(f(f(x))) \end{bmatrix}$ are injective.

Is there any way I can generalize the infectivity to N compositions?

My idea so far is to try to find an injective function that takes the map for $N = 1$, and gives the map for $N = 2$, and then try to prove for $N$ by induction, but so far I haven't made any progress

Comment: Unless you say something more about $X,$ I don't see how this is possible, as it is not obvious that $h$ is injective. For instance, if we take $x = (0, 0, 0, a, b, c)^t,$ then $h(x) = 0,$ but we can choose $a, b, c$ to be nonzero.

Comment: $h$ is not injective you're right. what is injective is the stacking of the compositions of $h$ and $f$. About $X$ the first three elements are a unit vector, I'll edit the e post

Comment: What if $f(x)$ is the projection onto the last three coordinates? We would have that $$\underbrace{(f \circ \cdots \circ f)(x)}_{n\text{-fold composition}} = f(x)$$ and $h(f(x)) = Cf(x) = 0,$ so any unit vector with first three coordinates equal to $0$ is in the kernel of $F.$

Comment: $f(x) : X \rightarrow X$, and $f(x) \neq x$.
I think i can prove using the fact that they are both Lipschitz, and using the results in this book:
Nik Weaver.Lipschitz Algebras.  World Scientific, 1999.

Comment: It would be useful to include this information in your original post.

Comment: I've edited the post accordingly